# django: queryset or filter on decimal field

Tags: python, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm trying to filter some objects on a queryset, field on what I'm trying is a Decimal...

model:

```
class CheckingAccount(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=False)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.balance)
```

form:

```
def clean(self):
    message = self.cleaned_data['acquisition_value']
    ow = Owner.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id)
    ca = CheckingAccount.objects.filter(balance=self.cleaned_data['checkingaccounts'])
```

The error I'm getting is:
Exception Value:
Cannot convert  to Decimal

Any idea?

Comment: balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)

do you have any more code for Ex. what is models, have you tried printing what it is returning before you try and convert it? and what type(models) returns ?

Comment: that is the value of `self.cleaned_data['checkingaccounts']`?

Comment: glss, yes, I've debbuged this and the value is: 230000.000000. I have a couple of models. One of the (RealState) has a form from where I need to get all checkingaccounts for a especified owner. Those checkingaccounts are loaded in a forms.ModelChoiceField (with a queryset) it works OK.

Before save the RealState form I use the clean method to validate that checking account has a sufficient balance to buy something. Here is where I cannot do this check because I cannot get this account.

Comment: ozgur, yes the value that I'm getting from the form is "self.cleaned_data['checkingaccounts']" Filled with this queryset:                                self.fields['checkingaccounts'].queryset = CheckingAccount.objects.filter(owner_id=(Owner.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.id)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might go wrong for several reasons, depending on cleaned_data returned value.

First - what if cleaned_data- fails and returns and exception or something like that ? your filter won't work :(
Second - It might be a decimal casting issue.

IMHO
Do not use cleaned_data in the filter.
Do your clean elsewhere, and filter with clear easy decimal number in the clean method.

Comment: Thanks, there was the problem.! As you said, this: `ca = CheckingAccount.objects.filter(balance=self.cleaned_data['checkingaccounts'])` doesn't has a Decimal, this has a CheckingAccout which has a balance incide. I've did this `a = self.cleaned_data['checkingaccounts']` `if ca.balance > self.cleaned_data['acquisition_value']` Thanks.!